# Can I use arrays in Java to store linked data

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I have a project where I want to store data about students(name,age,registration number etc)
I don't know how else to store the data so I thought arrays would be worthwhile.  How would I link data from the name array to the age array????

Comment: Consider writing a `Student` class.

Comment: A database is good also.

Answer (score 1):

In first, create a `Student` object like this:

```
public class Student {
    private final String name;
    private final int age;
    private final int registrationNumber;

    public Student(String name, int age, int registrationNumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.registrationNumber = registrationNumber;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public int getRegistrationNumber() {
        return registrationNumber;
    }
}
```

And after, you can create a list of `Student` who provide an in memory storage for your students:

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
students.add(new Student("Valentin", 23, 123456));
students.add(new Student("Alexander", 14, 82835));
```

I hope this gonna help you.